# Azure Log Analytics 1 log entry = 1 line

Tags: azure, logging

I have trouble using Log Analytics. It's quite hard to debug using this tool, probably because i'm using it badly.

Here what look like my Log Analytics:
[image]

I reproduce the error in local to explain my problem:

[image]

On logs it looke like 1 entry = 1 line of the error. But it's the same error, is it possible to merge all this entry into one entry with the full error ? Because it's hard to read when there is lot of logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To concatenate all log entries into one with the full error, use the
[`make_list()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/makelist-aggfunction)function to group the logs by a unique identifier and then concatenate the logs with the  [`array_concat()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/arrayconcatfunction) function.

I've taken a sample table in my environment as shown:

```bash
AppServiceHTTPLogs 
| summarize Logs = make_list(Log(number)) by _SubscriptionId
| extend FullError = array_concat(Logs,_SubscriptionId) | project FullError
```

Alternatively, I tried to filter the log entries to those that contain some error message and groups them based on their `resourceID` property, and then merges their message properties into a single list called `ErrorList`.

```bash
FunctionAppLogs
| where Message contains "error info/message"
| summarize ErrorList = make_list(logs(number)) by _ResourceId
| project _ResourceId, ErrorList
```

*Because I did not get any errors in the last hour, I got the below output, and you can try it in your environment to get the relevant results.*

[image]

Refer for more relevant examples of [KQL](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-log-query.md) queries.

Comment: I get an error :
Unknown function: 'Log'.

Comment: also I am using AppServicePlatformLogs and sending the logs to Datadog. how do I get it to log them as one line ?